# Regex for multiple MAC addresses separated by comma?

Tags: regex, delimiter, mac-address

I would like to know the correct regex for matching multiple MAC addresses separated my any delimiter, such as a comma.

The regex for a single MAC address would be: `^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$`.

So for multiple MAC addresses delimited by comma, i figured `^(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2},?)){+}$` would do the trick.

Where am i going wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Some people have asked about what went wrong. Well, simply put, the regex does not work. Let us say i enter a single (valid) MAC address, it is flagged as an invalid MAC address. Same goes for multiple MAC addresses delimited by comma.

The regex is needed for a validator for a textbox on an ASP .NET page. If more details are needed, let me know.

Comment: You went wrong when you didn't explain what went wrong.

Comment: You can have mac addresses not separated by a comma.  You need to have it match a list of length zero, one, or a comma separated list of >2.

Viz: ^$|MRE(,MRE)*

Comment: Using which regular expression engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(,([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*$`

See [Regex for Comma delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396084/regex-for-comma-delimited-list) for details about making a regex to match a delimited list. Basically you need to put the regex for a MAC address followed by a group containing a comma and the regex for a MAC address that is matched zero or more times. In your attempted solution the comma is completely optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(,([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}[-:]){5}(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}))(?:,|$)))+$
```

This ensures the octets is delimited by `:` or `-`.  No spaces or other characters are allowed.  The first group will capture all the mac addresses.  The match will capture the whole string, or fail to match if it isn't valid.