# jquery validate a comma separated list of integers

Tags: jquery

I have a form where the user is asked to enter a comma separated list of numbers (integers). How do I check their input with jquery during validation to verify that they have only entered numbers and commas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for Comma delimited list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396084/regex-for-comma-delimited-list) (of numbers)

Comment: `/[^\d,]+/.test(yourinputvalue)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the input (single digits) with this Regex:

```
^[0-9](,[0-9])*$
```

For long numbers, the regex is:

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

It forces user to avoid blanks or tabs.

To allow 0248 but not 00558, the new regex is:

```
^(([0]?[1-9][0-9]*)|[0])(,(([0]?[1-9][0-9]*)|[0]))*$
```

you can test it on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/yF0kE6/2)

Comment: Thanks this is working but only allows for one digit and then a comma. I am looking for any length of number in the comma separated list eg. 777,12,345,233,3

My code is:
$.validator.addMethod("mynumber", function (value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9](,[0-9])*$/.test(value);
}, "Please specify the correct number format");

Comment: Almost perfect however I notice I can still start a number with a 00 eg. 00558. With little knowledge of Regex I am unsure if that can be avoided?

Comment: Are you sure? The last version disable that possibility. When using 00558 in Regex 101 it says 00558 doesn't match the pattern. Which is good: [link with test](https://regex101.com/r/yF0kE6/3)

Comment: I beg your pardon - it does! Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

To allow any positve integer numbers in combination with blanks or tabs you could test with:

```
/^(\d+)(,\s*\d+\s*)*$/.test('1, 8   ,22')
--> true
```

**Update:**

If I understood your comment right and you also want to exclude numbers starting with a double '0' then the following should do the job:

```
var re=/^(\d?[1-9]+\d*)(,\s*\d?[1-9]+\d*\s*)*$/;
['1,2,3', 
 '01,02,03 , 040004, 05', 
 '001,002,3,4'].forEach(function(s){console.log(s,re.test(s));});
```

results:

```
"1,2,3"                 true
"01,02,03 , 040004, 05" true
"001,002,3,4"           false
```

**Second edit**

Actually, coming back to this question again I noticed that my previous solution excluded the '0' as a valid input. Here is the RegExp now that will allow that too (changed the `[1-9]+`-patterns to `[1-9]` according to Lithium's comment):

```
/^\s*(\d?([1-9]\d*)|0)\s*(,\s*(\d?[1-9]\d*|0)\s*)*$/
```

Unfortunately, it is not very short and snappy any more but it works.

Comment: thank you this worked for me. I would like to allow numbers like 0773 but not 00265 - any ideas?

Comment: What is the difference?!? The double '00' at the beginning or the total length of the number?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the 00 at the beginning. I am not concerned about the length of number

Comment: @cars the + in [1-9]+ is not useful. only one occurrence is enough then you can have multiple \d*

Comment: @Lithium: Yes, you are absolutely right. It was something I forgot to remove after having played around with it. Thanks for pointing it out - just changed it!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `.split()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) and validate every number in a loop. Or, if you only need to check if it is a number (no range or any other restrictions) then you can always use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396084/regex-for-comma-delimited-list) (see the [RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/prototype))