# Client side validation accept comma separated values

Tags: html, jquery

I am using the jQuery.validator.addClassRules method to validate my input fields. How do I allow my textbox to accept only comma seperated values and show the default message if incorrect.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control numberValidation" />


<!-- JS Plugins Init. -->
<script>
    $(document).on('ready',
        function () {

            $("#signupform").validate({

            errorClass: 'invalid-input'            

        });

        jQuery.validator.addClassRules('numberValidation',
        {
            number: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please share with us an example with valid and invalid input values

Comment: What inputs would you be considering as invalid?  You wouldn't want to invalidate if it doesn't have any commas because if you only had one item, it shouldn't have a comma at the end.

Comment: If you wrapped each item in single or double quotes, you could validate that the character inbetween, if there is more than one item, has to be a comma

Comment: @Dan Csharpster example 0,00

Comment: @ZainNabi, validation is more about what you're going to disallow.  You can validate something is a valid date, but often you're validating that its not a negative number, etc.  What is somebody tries to send strings with commas and then tries to separate them with semicolons, like:  foo,bar;123,,,456;abc;def  ?  Is that invalid input?  I would argue that its fine, it is valid input and just parse it on the commas and let the user see their bad input.  Maybe have a preview step before saving the values?

Comment: @Dan Csharpster way off topic.

Comment: Its actually not.  What are you considering invalid values?

Comment: @Dan Csharpster strings are not allowed. Only comma separated numbers are allowed e.g. 0,00 , 1,20

Answer (score 0):

If you combine [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/validate-a-textfield-and-use-regex) answer which shows you how to validate with a regular expression with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009998/jquery-validate-a-comma-separated-list-of-integers) answer that contains regex examples for comma separated integers, that should meet your needs.