# Pattern Matching In java for repeated pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want my string to match a pattern like this +cat,+dog,-name,+cat

So basically it should start with + or - followed by variable name and then ","

So I want to have a regex for the same for matching the string.

Could you please tell the regex for this pattern ?

Comment: What problems are you facing when writing such regex? What kind of help you need?

Comment: I have this regex ^([+-][a-zA-Z0-9_]*,)*$ but I want that it should not end with ",". How shall I modify the expression ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Regex for Comma delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1396084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches one instance of "+/- plus a variable name":

```
[+-]\w+
```

Now, to make it so that it matches multiple instances of the above, separated by commas, change it like this:

```
[+-]\w+(,[+-]\w+)*
```

Basically, I added this part:

```
(,[+-]\w+)*
```

It is a group that can repeat zero or more times (`*`), in the group, there is a comma, followed by the first pattern we saw.

Basically, you just need to move the comma to the start of the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ==> ^[+-]\w*[,]

Hope this help!