# Regex: Another way to match structure separated by commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want to know if a string is a collection of, by example, numbers (`[0-9]`).

I this case, i'm using the regular expression `[0-9](,[0-9])*` to find one or more numbers separated by commas (A collection of numbers).

Is there a better way to do it? I mean a shorter expression perhaps.

Comment: Impossible to say without a sample of the data - but if your data that need to be matched is single digits separate only by commas, only `\d(,\d)*` is a bit briefer

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396084/regex-for-comma-delimited-list) in which the top rated answer describes a regex pattern for extracting elements from a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following pattern:

```
(?<=^|,|\s)(\d+)
```

`(?<=...)` is a lookbehind assertion that **will not be captured** into the groups **nor be included** into the matched string. It is used to identify the starting position of the number to be matched.

You can try the above pattern interactively in the following website:

https://regex101.com/r/IKGWtA/1

Answer (score 0):

`\d*(,\d*)*` will catch the situation where you have multiple digits before and after a comma e.g. `100,000`. This regex will only grab `0,0` from that same number.

Comment: Should be `\d+` instead of `\d*` to ensure at least one digit. Using `*` will match "empty numbers" as in ``1,2,,,,3``.