# Java Proprties File

Tags: java

I was wondering, can I group properties in my property file?
This is content of my property file:

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=mkyong
```

I want to add to dbpassword more then 1 password. Can I do it?

Comment: Add more than one separated by a separator and then split the read property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you'd do this with some sort of manual "nesting":

```
foo.dbpassword=password
foo.database=localhost
foo.dbuser=mkyong

bar.dbpassword=...
...
```

But to be honest, by the time you've got a hierarchy, you should at least consider using a more naturally-hierarchical file format - XML springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple Properties file, you'd have to use

- either more than one key (eg `pwd1`, `pwd2`, etc. or `mybd1.pwd`, `mybd2.pwd`, etc.)
- a value with a separator and many paswords (eg `"mypass1 anotherpass"`)

Supposing you use the second scheme, you may be interested by [String splitting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to extract the different passwords.

Answer (score 0):

In property file,

> dbpassword=password1,password2

In java file,

```
String[] dbpasswords = properties.getProperty("dbpassword").split(",");
```

You should reference in [Multiple values in java.util.Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432481/multiple-values-in-java-util-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your properties as an XML file. It will be smth like:

```
<props>
    <database>
        <name>name1</name>
        <dbpass>pass1</dbpass>
        <dbuser>user1</dbuser>
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>name2</name>
        <dbpass>pass2</dbpass>
        <dbuser>user2</dbuser>
    </database>
</props>
```