# Spring - Injecting a list of dates from property file to a bean property

Tags: spring, list, properties, dependency-injection, jodatime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I specify values in a properties file so they can be retrieved using ResourceBundle#getStringArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226050/how-do-i-specify-values-in-a-properties-file-so-they-can-be-retrieved-using-reso)

I have a class like this:

```
public class BankHolidayCalendar {

    List<DateTime> bankHolidays;

    public BankHolidayCalendar(final List<DateTime> p_bankHolidays) {
        bankHolidays = p_bankHolidays;
    }
}
```

and a property file

```
# holidays.properties
holidayDates=01-01-2012, 13-02-2012, 22-04-2012
```

How can I read these dates from this property file and inject into the bean constructor?

I am using joda time here.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226050/how-do-i-specify-values-in-a-properties-file-so-they-can-be-retrieved-using-reso, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212898/spring-properties-file-get-element-as-an-array?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `@Value` annotation and create the `DateTime` object in the constructor like this:

```
public class BankHolidayCalendar {

    List<DateTime> bankHolidays = new ArrayList<DateTime>();

    public BankHolidayCalendar(@Value("holidayDates") String[] p_bankHolidays) {
        for (String date : p_bankHolidays) {
            bankHolidays.add(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample code above can be improved by using `Arrays.asList(p_bankHolidays)` instead of the `for` loop. See [documentation of Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).