# Bintray: Could not create package HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:License '[' does not exist]

Tags: deployment, gradle, gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to publish the first release of the [Overpass library](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass) to [Bintray/jCenter](http://bintray.com) using the [gradle-bintray-plugin v.1.5](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin). I prepared the configuration on this [temporary branch](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass/tree/release):

- [build.gradle](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass/blob/release/build.gradle)
- [deploy.gradle](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass/blob/release/gradle/deploy.gradle)
- [gradle.properties](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass/blob/release/gradle.properties)

I did not prepare anything on the Bintray website besides an account on which I published before. So I also have a `bintrayUser` and `bintrayApiKey` in place for Gradle. Please tell me if I need to manually setup something beforehand. - Then, I run the following command:

```
$ ./gradlew clean assemble bintrayUpload
```

This fails with this error:

> Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
>   > Could not create package 'tbsprs/maven/Overpass': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:License '[' does not exist]

Can you spot the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to release the library by **temporarily** replacing:

```
licenses = project.packageLicenses
```

with

```
licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
```

Note that I use *gradle.properties* to maintain these values in one place.
I already reported this behavior and hope the bug is fixed soon.

---

Here is the follow up issue for this case:

- https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/98

Comment: As far as I know the gradle.properties file cannot have list values, only String ones

Answer (score 1):

The gradle.properties file is a regular Java properties file and as such it [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226050/how-do-i-specify-values-in-a-properties-file-so-they-can-be-retrieved-using-reso) hold keys with multiple values.
A simple solution would be having a comma delimited string in the properties file, for example:

```
licenses=Apache-2.0,BSD
```

And splitting this value in build.gradle to create an array

```
licenses = project.property('licenses').split(',')
```

Comment: You might want to suggest your solution [here](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/98).

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you shared your `build.gradle`, but my guess would be you don't have the mandatory `license` field in the `pkg` block.

Comment: It's right [there](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass/blob/release/build.gradle).

Comment: The field name is `licenses` and its right [there](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Overpass/blob/release/gradle/deploy.gradle#L42).