# How to load multiple properties separated by colon

Tags: java, xml, configuration, xml-parsing, configuration-files

abc.properties:

```
engine.xpath=messageHeader/messageId:1234, systemIdentifier/tradeId:4567, .....
```

I need to read multiple XPATHs from properties: value to be changed at that XPATH.

Comment: @aldok: Earlier I was reading individual XPATHs and individual VALUES, so it was easy. Now in need to read multiple dependent properties... Can we use HashMap<String,String>? And save <XPATH, Value>? And then later iterate it and change value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226050/how-do-i-specify-values-in-a-properties-file-so-they-can-be-retrieved-using-reso  you have the answer here

Comment: @Shree Nath: Not exactly... I am aware and have used String[ ] to load multiple properties separated by comma, but here, every comma further has two dependent properties seperated by colon which needs to be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the comma-separated properties, use `StringTokenizer`:

```
java.util.StringTokenizer st = new java.util.StringTokenizer(property, ":");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```